# Facebook Sharing API - Specify Different Image for Object on Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know how to set the OG tags for pages to specify an image, but here is my situation:

I have a page with 4 shareable objects.  One leads to a page with it's own open graph tags, so he's okay.  The other three would share a link to an anchor position on the same page.  How could I make each of those get their own image?

So for instance:

Shareable 1: http://www.demo.com/page   <---  FB get's the OG tags from that page
Shareable 2: http://www.demo.com/home#video <-- FB get's OG tag from home, I want to specify a different image
Shareable 3: http://www.demo.com/home#photos <-- FB get's OG tag from home, I want to specify a different image
Shareable 4: http://www.demo.com/home#cheese <-- FB get's OG tag from home, I want to specify a different image

Comment: You can still specify properties such as the thumbnail image at runtime by using the Feed dialog to let the user share. But I doubt this will link to the right anchor position on the page when a user clicks the link someone shared on Facebook. If you want to share different pieces of content, you should really rather have different pages as well. (F.e. your custom image will be ignored if someone re-shares the shared link, then AFAIK will use the image from the OG meta tag again.)

Answer (score 0):

Information afer a hashtags gets ignored, you have to do it with rewrite or with a parameter, for example:

```
http://www.demo.com/home?id=xxx
http://www.demo.com/home/video
```